# How do you import an xprv using descriptors and importmulti?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I have figured out how to import an xpub, but when i use `getdescriptorinfo` on an xprv:

```
getdescriptorinfo "wpkh(xprvA1Gpa5TRogN9eRoBFZLAEKjfvxzXTZpNpuJ9WXvTsRT3ZoW1EFnrAXji4aYPAktDc5ZYgAcS8XH5npiUdVztxdyrig2rZvNsrTEbhz1x2KQ/*)"
```

it returns

```
{
  "descriptor": "wpkh(xpub6EGAyazKe3vSruseMasAbTgQUzq1s2YEC8DkJvL5Rkz2Sbq9mo76iL4Buq1opb9EeNfB2DzqeCuuDMcpx2ZTkcJdnp24Sa8Qo7CgwfbGrD1/*)#2p7j3v7x",
  "isrange": true,
  "issolvable": true,
  "hasprivatekeys": true
}
```

The descriptor is an xpub? Why? It sees that the key has private keys. If I use this descriptor with `importmulti` and specify a range will it import the private keys and addresses? I was expecting `getdescriptorinfo` to return an xprv. If this is not how you import an xprv then how do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getdescriptorinfo` always returns the non-private key from of the descriptor (security precaution).

From the commands help text:

`"descriptor" :  (string) The descriptor in canonical form, without private keys`

Comment: So the private keys will get automatically imported with the xprv descriptor?

Comment: This is incorrect. `importprivkey` ignores private keys in descriptors; you need to provide them separately in WIF format (for now; this will likely be improved in 0.19).

Comment: I removed my missing/wrong comment (could not edit).